# How to inspect value of method parameter in IntelliJ debugger?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a way to inspect the value of method parameters from within IntelliJ's debugger?

It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/debug-tool-window-frames.html), and when I try to select the parameter name and use `Alt + F8`, it says "Cannot find local variable":

[image: cannot evaluate method parameter]

Nor does it list the method parameters in the Variables window:

[image: method parameter not listed in Variables window]

Note: The method whose parameters I am inspecting is not the *current* (top) stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the wrong tool window. I need to use the "Frames" tool window instead of the "Threads" tool window to select which stack frame I want to inspect. When you click a stack frame in the "Frames" window, it will update the "Variables" window to show the method parameters for that specific frame.